# When converting a string column to int column, I am getting error "conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'NULL' to data type int."

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update the column type to int using the code below

```
Alter table Customers_Practice1
Alter column SalesRepEmployeeNumber int
```

It gives me the error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'NULL' to data type int."

From another post, I realized that NULL is being read as a string value rather than just NULL and the following code works with a select statement

```
Select Replace(SalesrepemployeeNumber,'NULL','0') from Customers_Practice1
```

But when I tried using it with the Alter statement using the code below it didn't work.

```
Alter table Customers_Practice1
Alter column (Select Replace(SalesRepEmployeeNumber,'NULL','0') 
as SalesRepEmployeeNumber from Customers_Practice1) int
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to search google for it? This is the first result for your error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428933/conversion-failed-when-converting-the-varchar-value-null-to-data-type-int

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for `update`:

```
update Customers_Practice1
    SalesrepemployeeNumber = Replace(SalesrepemployeeNumber, 'NULL', '0')
    where SalesrepemployeeNumber like '%NULL%';
```

However, if you want to set string null values, `'NULL'`, to `NULL`:

```
update Customers_Practice1
    set SalesrepemployeeNumber = NULL
    where SalesrepemployeeNumber = 'NULL';
```

Don't confuse `NULL` and `0`.  They are not the same thing.

If this is the only problem, you can then do:

```
Alter table Customers_Practice1
    Alter column int;
```

Comment: Thanks!! just an update on the "update" part of the code, I think we need to use "SET" before "Salesrepemployeenumber= ......", but the whole thing totally worked for me.

Comment: @AmitSinghParihar . . . Good catch.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Just to build on Gordon's answer (+1),

Before you run the ALTER TABLE, I would check to see if any other conversion failures.

```
Select *
 From  Customers_Practice1
 Where Try_Convert(int,SalesRepEmployeeNumber) is null
```

Answer (score 0):

you can fix the invalid data first, than doing alter column

```
UPDATE  Customers_Practice1 SET SalesRepEmployeeNumber=
      CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SalesRepEmployeeNumber)=1 THEN SalesRepEmployeeNumber ELSE 0 END 
GO
Alter table Customers_Practice1 Alter column SalesRepEmployeeNumber int
```